# How do I register a new extension with QuickLook in Mac OS 10.7?

Tags: macos, text-files, quicklook

I really like the QuickLook feature in the Mac Finder and often use it to look in text files without opening them in an editor. I work with a number of file types that are text files but have extensions that QuickLook doesn't recognize.

How do I tell QuickLook that files with various extensions (.rst, .aux, etc) are plain text and can be previewed just like .txt files?

I have seen solutions involving hacking plists that were valid in 10.5 and 10.6, but having looked into it, it seems that 10.7 handles things differently.

Comment: belongs on another SE site, has dupe at https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/47319/how-can-i-make-os-x-recognize-new-file-extensions